# Put 2 line charts to one Google Chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to put 2 graphics with different scale to one Google Chart:

```
var options = {
          curveType: 'function',
          legend: { position: 'bottom' },
          vAxis: {
            0: {
                gridlines: { count: 10 },
                viewWindow:{
                  max:250,
                  min:0
                }
            },
            1: {
                gridlines: { count: 10 },
                viewWindow:{
                  max:20000,
                  min:0
                }
            },
          },
          series:{
                0:{targetAxisIndex:0},
                1:{targetAxisIndex:1}
          },
          'chartArea': {'width': '90%', 'height': '75%'}
        };
```

But I received this result:
[image]

All the data is positive numbers for both charts. Why I received -100 on the left side? What is wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: can you post the data?

Comment: Data are all positive integers. A lot of items, more than 500, so I can't post. Blue chart is from 0 till 250, red one from 0 till 17000. Positive integers in this ranges.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is quite simple:

`hAxis` and `vAxis` contain the options of the horizontal and vertical axes, respectively. And if you want **multiple** vertical axes, you have to use **`vAxes` (not `vAxis`)!!!**

Comment: I've encountered this before, too. Simple mistake, yields unpredictable results.